# How rename "mvn spring-boot:run" to "mvn someName:run"?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm still learning and I have a question, can I run not only through the "Spring Boot". Or reassign that would be more interesting. Prompt please in what direction to dig.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It’s not really in the maven way. Could you be more clear about what you want to achieve?

Comment: You could try https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html

Comment: I'm actually very interested. From the category of why not?
I want to change the **spring-boot** to any plain name of mine.

Comment: I thank this that I tried unsuccessfully to find.

Comment: Well this does not work in `spring-boot-maven-plugin`.

Comment: `spring-boot` is the name of the plugin; you don't change it. Perhaps what you want to do is to run `mvn package` to produce a fat jar and then `java -jar my-app.jar`.

Comment: @Egor Drakonov because it’s the name of the plugin so you would have to change the plugin to do what you want. Like I said, it’s not the maven way. You could hide this in a sh or cmd script but I advise you not to do that because the purpose of maven is to be consistent between project.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's not possible without modifying the plugin pom: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-maven-plugin/pom.xml

Maven plugins follow a name pattern `<artifactId>plugin-name-maven-plugin</artifactId>`

In the spring-boot is `<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>`

So you can call `mvn spring-boot:run`

Maybe what you want is to create your own plugin: https://dzone.com/articles/a-simple-maven-3-plugin